# Using the compareTo(String) to alphabetize strings in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, compare

Basically I have an employees array that has commission, salary, and hourly employees.  I need to display an alphabetized list of the employees.  If the last names are the same the first names also need to be alphabetized.  How do I go about doing this.

Comment: What exactly does your array contain? Is it an array of objects with the values you mention or what? Also you don't mention the array containing the name, so where does that come from?

Comment: The array has the first and last names in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Arrays.sort(employees, new Comparator<Employee>() {
  public int compare(Employee a, Employee b) {
    int cmp = a.getLastName().compareTo(b.getLastName());
    if (cmp == 0) {
      cmp = a.getFirstName().compareTo(b.getFirstName());
    }
    return cmp;
  }
});
```

Or, using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) to get something more readable and less bug-prone,

```
Arrays.sort(employees, new Comparator<Employee>() {
  public int compare(Employee a, Employee b) {
    return ComparisonChain.start()
      .compare(a.getLastName(), b.getLastName())
      .compare(a.getFirstName(), b.getFirstName())
      .result();
  }
});
```